# Creating authorities table in mysql for user authentication

Tags: mysql

I looked through different tutorials to find out the best practice for creating authorities table for user authentication and found such a solution several times:

```
CREATE TABLE user_roles (
user_role_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(45) NOT NULL,
role varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (user_role_id),
UNIQUE KEY uni_username_role (role,username),
KEY fk_username_idx (username),
CONSTRAINT fk_username FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username));
```

Could you help me understand what does the `KEY fk_username_idx (username)` line stands for? How is it useful?

We are using username as a foreign key in this table. That means that it will be a primary key in the users table. Isn't it a bad practice to make primary keys a non-integer value?

Comment: You seem to have understood the meaning of `KEY fk_username_idx (username)` perfectly well. Yes, you should avoid having long string fields as a pk, but in some instances it is unavoidable.

Comment: So fk_username_idx is an index that deals with foreign key username?

Comment: In order for FKs to work, all referencing and referenced fields must be indexed. FK creates an implicit index on the referencing fields if none are present, but you can create your own one.

Comment: what may be the reason to create an explicit index?

Comment: I cannot guess why sy else chose to create an explicit index in this particular case. But it does not really matter.

Comment: So if I omit it `KEY fk_username_idx (username)` it should still work and won't influence the speed of query execution as there will be an implicit index and no delete or update operations are involved?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? (Performance cannot be an issue because you have to have the required indexes)

Comment: It appears to be working fine. As I looked through the answers I found that in earlier versions of mysql you had to explicitly define index. Thanks!